# Jquery slideToggle destroys iframe

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

Posting all of the code here is going to be impossible considering the project I'm working with however here is the general scenario.

I have a div tag which is collapsed using JQuery like so:

```
$(".div_class").click(function(){
    $("div#div_name").slideToggle()
});
```

This function affects an IFrame later on the page.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="iframe_id" name="iframe_name" height="100%" width="100%" src="google.com"></iframe>
```

Here is the problem, my div contains and IFrame, when the box re-expands, it will not display the IFrame.  Even stranger, if I right click toward the bottom of the box, and use firebug to inspect element, it will shuffle the screen for a split second and the IFrame will show again.

As a bit of clarification, the slider is not affecting the IFrame directly, its collapsing the div, which encapsulates the iframe.

Have already attempted to set the IFrame css 'display' to 'block' which seemed to be the gist of what the JQuery function was doing but it didn't resolve.  Also attempted to add to the JQuery function and insert a new IFrame after click but this failed as well.

Thank you ahead of time for any input.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that height="100%" on iframe is not really doing 100% the content in it. Height 100% means it will "spread" on the height of the parent, but what you need is height of the content, I think. Try setting a fix height and see if the same problem occures.

As well, you might consider [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) .

Comment: The height/width I updated to be 300x300 and it immediately fixed it.  Thank you!